# Wordpress contact-form-7 plugin do something before mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have got a wordpress instance with the plugin contact-form-7. In some tutorials, I saw that I can do something before sending the mail with this code:

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");

function wpcf7_do_something_else(&$wpcf7_data) {

    // Here is the variable where the data are stored!
    var_dump($wpcf7_data);

    // If you want to skip mailing the data, you can do it...
    $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;

}
```

I got the code from here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mini-guide-to-contact-form-7--wp-25086

But somehow, it is not working. I don't receive any error - the contact form is not sending the mail anymore, even without the `$wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true`, and it doesn't print anything.

My questions:

Where do I have to write this code? Directly into the plugin? (At the moment, I wrote this code into a custom plugin, maybe wrong?)
Is it even possible to print any data from the form in there? (Is the tutorial bad?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is normal that the contact form does not send email anymore, as it is defined on this line `$wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;`.

This code is used if you want **something else than the default posting (sending in email)**, as described in the tutorial.

This code, however, *should be placed* in your theme's `functions.php` file (if file exists, create it). But still, the email *will not be send*.

If you want to skip emails and perform other action, then leave this piece of code

`$wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;`

and add your logic after this line.

Describe more precisely **what do you want to do (instead of sending email)** in your question.

Comment: Well i don't really care about the e-mail anyways. I just want it to print something. ( And later make changes to the sent data). And even without ->skip_mail hes not sending any e-mail anymore. sorry, i will clarify this in my answer.

Comment: I have wrote this into a functions.php into web/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php but its still not working, do i have to write the add_action somewhere else? -> I wanna print $wpcf7_data out.

Comment: The file is `functions.php`, with an `s`, at the end.

Comment: Yea I wrote it in there, but still nothing happens^^ Where do i have to write add_action("wpcf7....")? I wrote it into the functions.php aswell

Comment: The whole piece of code should go in `functions.php`, including the `add_action(...)`

Comment: What add_filter? I just got an add_action here?! -> nvm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51654/discussion-between-xatenev-and-bodi0)